# Why dont dpkg logs record software removed as part of the installtion process?

Tags: apt, system-installation, dpkg, ubiquity, logs

The manifest for the Desktop image of Ubuntu 20.04 is available [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.manifest). Some of the packages listed in the manifest are removed during the installation process. For example, `ubiquity`, `ubiquity-casper`, `ubiquity-frontend-gtk`, and `ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu` are all removed (to mention just a few). This can be seen by looking in the very first `history.log`, probably archived by now, in `/var/log/apt/` for the section beginning with something like:

```
Start-Date: ...
Requested-By: ubuntu (999)
Purge: ...
```

Running something like `apt policy ubiquity ubiquity-casper ubiquity-frontend-gtk ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu` will confirm their absence.

However, the removal of these packages by this automatic "Purge:", is not recorded in the very first `dpkg.log` (covering the installation process).

If a user runs

```
zgrep "status installed ubiquity" /var/log/dpkg.log*
```

the result is this (assuming the relevant archived log is still available) giving the impression that the packages are still installed:

```
$ zgrep "status installed ubiquity" /var/log/dpkg.log*
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:40:38 status installed ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork:all 20.04.15
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:40:43 status installed ubiquity-casper:all 1.445
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:40:43 status installed ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu:all 160
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:42:15 status installed ubiquity-frontend-gtk:amd64 20.04.15
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:42:18 status installed ubiquity:amd64 20.04.15
$
```

Is it that the installation of software is handled by `dpkg`, but this `Purge` step is not handled by `dpkg`? Or what is the reason for not the dpkg log not showing that these various packages were removed (as correctly shown in apt's history.log)?

---

---

---

I'm asking the same question but in a different way.

This is an annotated extract (with long lines truncated) of my `/var/log/history.log` from the date I installed Ubuntu 20.04.
`2:`, `3:`, etc are line numbers included for ease of reference:

```
2: Start-Date: 2020-04-23  07:34:03
3: Commandline: apt-get --yes -oDebug::pkgDepCache::AutoInstall=yes install linux-generic-hwe-20.04 adduser apt apt-utils ...
4: Install: speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng:amd64 (0.9.1-4)Install: speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng:amd64 (0.9.1-4)
5: End-Date: 2020-04-23  07:39:30

7: Start-Date: 2020-04-23  07:39:39
8: Commandline: apt-get --yes -oDebug::pkgDepCache::AutoInstall=yes install lupin-casper ...
9: Install: hunspell-en-gb:amd64 (1:6.4.3-1), cryptsetup-bin:amd64 ...
10: End-Date: 2020-04-23  07:42:21

12: Start-Date: 2020-04-26  16:12:11
13: Requested-By: ubuntu (999)
14: End-Date: 2020-04-26  16:12:12

16: Start-Date: 2020-04-26  16:13:28
17: Requested-By: ubuntu (999)
18: End-Date: 2020-04-26  16:13:29

20: Start-Date: 2020-04-26  16:14:08
21: Requested-By: ubuntu (999)
22: Purge: hunspell-en-gb:amd64 ...
23: End-Date: 2020-04-26  16:19:54

25: Start-Date: 2020-04-26  16:19:57
26: Requested-By: ubuntu (999)
27: End-Date: 2020-04-26  16:19:58

29: Start-Date: 2020-04-26  16:20:00
30: Requested-By: ubuntu (999)
31: End-Date: 2020-04-26  16:20:00

33: Start-Date: 2020-04-26  16:24:48
34: Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.105'
35: Upgrade: netplan.io:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu1, 0.99-0ubuntu2), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.43ubuntu1, 0.43ubuntu1.1), libnetplan0:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu1, 0.99-0ubuntu2)
36: End-Date: 2020-04-26  16:25:01
```

So let's take the example of `hunspell-en-gb` which can be installed without any dependencies. (You may prefer to use some other language version which has been removed from your system in line #22.)

It has been *installed* according to line #9.
Later, the same package is *purged* according to line 22.

The absence of this package on my system can be verified by running `apt policy 2>/dev/null hunspell-en-gb` which shows

```
hunspell-en-gb:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:6.4.3-1
```

I would expect that querying `/var/log/dpkg.log.1` (or the appropriate archived log) would reflect that.

```
$ zgrep hunspell-en-gb /var/log/dpkg*
dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:39:54 install hunspell-en-gb:all <none> 1:6.4.3-1
dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:39:54 status half-installed hunspell-en-gb:all 1:6.4.3-1
dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:39:54 status unpacked hunspell-en-gb:all 1:6.4.3-1
dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:40:43 configure hunspell-en-gb:all 1:6.4.3-1 <none>
dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:40:43 status unpacked hunspell-en-gb:all 1:6.4.3-1
dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:40:43 status half-configured hunspell-en-gb:all 1:6.4.3-1
dpkg.log.1:2020-04-23 07:40:43 status installed hunspell-en-gb:all 1:6.4.3-1
$
```

There is no line with "status not-installed" which is normally present if a package has been successfully removed using `sudo apt purge ...`. You can check this for **any** package listed in line #22.

Normally,
- if a package is present on one system and was installed using `sudo apt install`, the dpkg logs in `/var/log` show that package with `status:installed` once for the initial install and then repeatedly for each update of that package
- if that package is removed using `sudo apt purge`, the dkpg logs normally reflect that with `status not-installed` (each time that package is removed).

Just for confirmation, now run `sudo apt install hunspell-en-gb` followed by `sudo apt purge hunspell-en-gb`. Then, query the dpkg logs again:

$ zgrep -E "status (not-)?installed hunspell-en-gb:" /var/log/dpkg.log* | sed 's/:/: /' | sort -k2,3 -r | column -t
/var/log/dpkg.log:    2020-05-20  15:36:09  status  not-installed  hunspell-en-gb:all  
/var/log/dpkg.log:    2020-05-20  15:36:08  status  installed      hunspell-en-gb:all  1:6.4.3-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:    2020-05-20  15:35:51  status  installed      hunspell-en-gb:all  1:6.4.3-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:  2020-04-23  07:40:43  status  installed      hunspell-en-gb:all  1:6.4.3-1
$

Notice the first line (because of the sorting) has `status  not-installed`. And that is exactly what is missing from the dpkg logs for the packages removed during the installation. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

As for me - this is done for data safety and for getting some clues after installation if something went wrong.

Technically such purge or removal is done by `package.prerm` or `package.postrm` [maintenance scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) located in `/var/lib/dpkg/` (located here if the package is currently installed).

For example I have package `sysstat` installed on my system, its `sysstat.postrm` script [contains the line](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysstat/-/blob/master/debian/sysstat.postrm#L11) for removing its logs from `/var/log/sysstat` on its purge.

Then lets analyze packages from your post:

- `ubiquity`, `ubiquity-frontend-gtk` - [does not own](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/ubiquity/filelist) any files in `/var/log`, [does not have](https://git.launchpad.net/ubiquity/tree/debian) mentions of `/var/log` in `*.*rm` files;
- `ubiquity-casper` - [does not own](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/ubiquity-casper/filelist) any files in `/var/log`, [does not have](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/casper/casper_1.445.tar.xz)  `*.*rm` files;
- `ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu` - [does not own](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu/filelist) any files in `/var/log`, [does not have](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubiquity-slideshow/ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu/html/files/head:/debian) `*.*rm` files.

So these package do not have post-removal directives for removing log-files.

Comment: I think I will edit my question to make it more clear. I will ping you then.

Comment: Please take a look whenever you can. I hope the issue is clearer now.